# Specify selected columns in Eloquent model class rather than querybuilder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Whenever I use an eloquent model, it will select *, unless I specify it in a querybuilder object. However, I want to specify allowed fields in the class. This would be useful for ensuring the correct user level gets the details they are entitled to, so it property live with the class.

I want to be able to do it as a member variable, like $with:

```
/**
 * @property mixed id
 */
class Attribute extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ["id", "business_id", "attribute_name"];
    protected $with = ["attributeDetail", "business"];
    protected $selectedFieldsThatMeanSelectStarDoesntHappen = ["id", "business_id", "attribute_name"];
}
```

So any query using the above class will do `SELECT id, business_id, attribute_name` whenever the class is used, and not `SELECT *`.

Does the above functionality exist? The closest I can get is with a global scope:

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('selectFields', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->select("id", "business_id", "attribute_name");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what about a global scope? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: @lagbox Nice one, I didnt think of that. I would like to see something like in my question in laravel, but a global scope would achieve what im looking for

Comment: For some control over the shown/hidden attribute depending on the user, you should use collection resources or jsonResponse (if it's an api). https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it:
Create a new builder and a trait to use this new builder:

```php
class BuilderWithSpecifiedColumns extends Builder
{
    public $selectedColumns = [];

    public function __construct(ConnectionInterface $connection, Grammar $grammar = null, Processor $processor = null, array $selectedColumns = ['*'])
    {
        parent::__construct($connection, $grammar, $processor);
        $this->selectedColumns = $selectedColumns;
    }

    /**
     * @param string[] $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function get($columns = ['*'])
    {
        return parent::get($this->selectedColumns ? $this->selectedColumns : $columns);
    }
}
```

```php
trait HasSelectedColumns
{
    protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        return new BuilderWithSpecifiedColumns(
            $connection,
            $connection->getQueryGrammar(),
            $connection->getPostProcessor(),
            $this->selectedFieldsThatMeanSelectStarDoesntHappen,
        );
    }
}
```

Use above trait

```php
/**
 * @property mixed id
 */
class Attribute extends Model
{
    use HasSelectedColumns;

    protected $fillable = ["id", "business_id", "attribute_name"];
    protected $with = ["attributeDetail", "business"];
    protected $selectedFieldsThatMeanSelectStarDoesntHappen = ["id", "business_id", "attribute_name"];
}
```